# Sampling in Digital Controller

Tags: digital-control

I have a digital control loop in which the controller (difference equation) is getting calculated at a rate of 10kHz. The feedback signal is at a much lower sampling frequency around 100Hz. The loop crossover is expected to be around 10Hz.

Assuming I want to check the behavior of the loop gain in S domain using bilinear transformation

[image]

I think T in the equation should be according to 10kHz of the controller. Am I getting this right?

More details:
The output I am trying to control is DC with a 100Hz ripples. By sampling at specific points as shown I am hoping to eliminate the ripples from passing to the controller. The 10kHz controller is decided by the code structure and I was trying to figure out what the model would look like if I sample at this low freq. Will I have to include a delay term like e^(-s*(1/100)) while treating the digital system as 10kHz?

[image]

The controller is a simple digital PI: P + I*Z/(Z-1).
The zero crossing of the 100Hz ripples are reliably detected in the system. So, even if it shifts or the frequency move a bit around 100Hz, the sampling always happens at the zero crossings.

Comment: Loop gain is not measured in Hz.  Do you mean the closed-loop control bandwidth?  For stability purposes your sampling period is the rate at which you are sampling the analog input to your controller.

Comment: @JohnD you are correct. I meant the loop cross over. I just edited the post.
Your exactly correct, but don't you think that in my case the controller output will be updated between the samples of the feedback ? Say for example I have a integration action in the compensator.

Comment: What is your rationale for running the controller at a higher rate than your feedback?  Do you have more than one feedback, at different rates?  Are you smoothing the output somehow?  Are you trying to deal with a plant resonance?  Without some special reason, there's generally little point in running the controller at a different speed than the feedback.

Comment: @TimWescott Yes, I am trying to smooth the output which has a ripple of 100Hz and it deteriorates the performance of the system if the loop reacted to it.

Comment: Please *edit your question* with that information, along with detail of how you're smoothing the ripple -- it matters.

Comment: @RMS Yes, the controller output will be updated between samples, so if you're only looking for the transfer function between the input and output of your controller, you can use the higher sample rate.  If you're interested in the overall loop gain and how it affects system stability, then you have to add in the blocks with the lower sample rate with their appropriate frequency response.

Comment: I don't understand the rationale of avoiding 100 Hz ripple by updating the output at 10 kHz but still keeping the input at 100 Hz. Due to the staircase input at 100 Hz, won't the output still contain 100 Hz component? Or is there a filter which specifically removes the 100 Hz from the 10kHz output. In that case, I would suggest treating the system as a 100 Hz discrete time system with an "*effectively continuous time*" 100 Hz ripple removing filter at its output. Consider adding a detailed block diagram to the question showing the various individual filter blocks and their periodicity.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the input. I updated the post with more details.

Comment: **1** Could you post the internal structure of the digital filter too; no need for numbers, but a break up in terms of LPFs, HPFs, BPFs etc. **2** The way you have marked the red arrows to show that 100 Hz ripple is *bypassed* using 100 Hz sampling. What happens if the ripple shifts to 100.5 Hz and sampling remains at 100 Hz ? This doesn't look like a robust solution IMO.

Comment: The zero crossing of the 100Hz ripples are reliably detected in the system. So, even if it shifts or the frequency move a bit around 100Hz, the sampling always happens at the zero crossings. I updated the post with G(z) structure.

Comment: **1** My suggestion is to analyse the system as having a discrete time part running at 100 Hz with the part running at 10 kHz approximated as a continuous time system just like the plant. Actual controller update with actual new information occurs at 100 Hz. The 99 additional samples generated are all determined by the same set of input that the 1st output depended on. **2** The comment above effectively makes the system non uniform sampling period system IMO. **3** Please add the information in the comments above directly to the question as they seem important IMO.

Comment: @AJN Thanks for your input.
Is the system considered multirate sampled system?